# How to compile the java code generated by swagger-codegen

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

I am trying to write an example code to talk to the `swaggerjavaclient` created by `swagger-codegen`. I have my code structure as follows:

```
|_java
  |_  src
    |_    examplecode
          |_  example.java
     |_   swaggerjavaclient
           |_ src/main/java/io/swagger/client/api

           |_ otherswaggergeneratedfiles
           |_ pom.xml
```

I am getting this: `error: package io.swagger.client does not exist` when I run `example.java` which looks like below:

```
import io.swagger.client.ApiClient;
import io.swagger.client.api.DefaultApi;

public class example {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   // Code to talk to swaggerjavaclient
 }
}
```

When I put the structure as

```
|_java
  |_  src
      |_  swaggerjavaclient
          |_  examplecode
              |_ example.java
          |_  src/main/java/io/swagger/client/api

          |_ otherswaggergeneratedfiles
```

in Eclipse, I am able to compile and run this code.

I have two questions:

1. How can I have the original structure (have the examplecode outside of swaggerjavaclient directory) and still be able to compile and run the code?
2. How do I build and run this code from terminal?

Comment: I'm skeptical this actually compiles in Eclipse as you posted it. Assuming `src` is your source folder, the full name for `ApiClient` is `swaggerjavaclient.src.main.java.io.swagger.client.api.ApiClient`. Maybe read up a bit on packages and common project structure (typically `src/main/java`, not `java/src/`)

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider in Eclipse when I do `Import --> maven --> Existing maven projects` and then choose root directory as `java/src`, it creates a project named `swagger-java-client` instead of `swaggerjavaclient` mentioned above. because the `pom.xml` is in the folder `swaggerjavaclient`, it doesn't take the `clientexample` folder and only adds the `swaggerjavaclient` contents into the maven project.

My problem is I want to have the `clientexample` and `swaggerjavaclient` within the same folder and run them